# Knockout bind multiple observables to a single custom bindingHandler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to bind two observables to a single custom binding. The following snippet works as I'd expect with a single observable:

Markup:

```
Column:
<select data-bind="options: $root.ColumnDetails,
    value: column,
    optionsText: 'Name',
    values: Name,
    optionsCaption: 'Select Column...'"></select>

Operator:
<select data-bind="options: $root.Operators,
    value: operator,
    optionsText: 'DisplayName',
    values: Name,
    optionsCaption: 'Select Operator...'"></select>

Values:
<input type="text" data-bind="expressionValues: operator">
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.expressionValues = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        // do stuff

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

The above code works as expected, firing the update event of the custom binding when the value of the operator drop down is changed. However, my desired result is to bind both of the selects to the binding handler and have the update fire when either one is changed.

I tried setting it up this way but the update event doesn't fire for either:

```
Values:
<input type="text" data-bind="expressionValues: [ operator, column ]">
```

Any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Comment: Your approach seems right but if you still cant get it to work, one option is to use an object instead of array. <input type="text" data-bind="expressionValues:{ operator:operator, column: column }">. Another option is that you might be able to create a computed observable based on the two properties (operator, column) and bind that to the customBinding.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing an object with observables to your binding like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="expressionValues: { valueOperator: operator, valueColumn }">
```

And reference them through `valueAccessor` in your binding handler functions like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.expressionValues = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {       
            var parameters = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            var operator = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.valueOperator);
            var column = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.valueColumn);

            // do stuff

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var parameters = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            var operator = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.valueOperator);
            var column = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(settings.valueColumn);

            // do stuff

        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion you (and Krishna) made. However, the binding handler's update event does not fire when either of the observables are changed (via selecting a different item in the drop downs). If I use just one of the observables, it fires the update event as I would expect. I think I might try going down the computed route that Krishna suggested but I was really hoping I could just use a custom binding.